# How do you make sure both variables are the same but also are in the right place

Tags: lego-mindstorms

I am making a simple game in **LEGO EV3** programmer (default software) and I have a code that I don't know how I'd make.

I have 2 variables -

- if player is in the right spot,
- if bullet is in the right spot.

I want to make it so it is compared, and if the variables both equal, and are in the same position, it makes another variable true.

Therefore...

```
if ((IF PLAYER & IF OBJECT) = SAME) & ((IF PLAYER = TRUE) & (IF OBJECT = TRUE)) then VARIABLE = TRUE;
```

Or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should not have "if if" anywhere, that just looks wrong.

What do you mean by "if player = true"? This doesn't make sense when you read it. A player cannot be true.

The code should look like `if player = bullet then shot = true`. This assumes that the `player` and the `bullet` variables represent the location of these objects. (I know nothing about Mindstorms, by the way.) Maybe you need to replace the first `=` with `==`, depending on how the programming language needs it.

Answer (score 0):

What language that you use?

I am used python to wrote code in my brick before.

So I may code as this:

```
spotA = player.spot()
spotB = object.spot()
anotherVer = false

if spotA == spotB:
    anotherVer = true
```

And also, I think in all languages, that relational expression is use like

```
==
!=
||
&&
```

etc.

Hope this will help you. :)